# What are the following equations called?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, redox, terminology

Our teacher was writing out the following ways of expressing redox and she used a particular term for what these equations are called. When we write out the following what is this called? Its a way to show what atoms lose and gain electrons, but I forgot what these are called:

$$
\begin{align}
\ce{Li &-> Li+ + e-}\\
\ce{F + e- &-> F-}
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 4):

Those are called **half-reactions** because they show how electrons associate or dissociate, but don’t show the full reaction. I believe that’s the term you’re looking for!

Comment: @user54747 If you are happy with the answer, don't forget to click "Accept" (looks like "v" on the left) button – this is your way of expressing gratitude on SX sites:)

Comment: @andselisk Dont see it.

Comment: @user54747 Then see the [tour](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/tour), please.